# In wpf, is there a way to execute code before the control is unloaded...? like maybe an unloading event?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to execute code before a wpf user control is unloaded and cancel the unloading if certain conditions are met and keep the control open in its current state in the ui...

Is there any way I can accomplish this? I couldnt see anything like unloading event?
Thanks,

Comment: What is your use case for this? It sounds like you want something that works like Window.Closing which is a lot different than canceling a FrameworkElement.Unloaded event. There can be a lot happening around layout of parents and siblings when an element is being unloaded.

Comment: I have a similar problem, just in case you can help me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310724/wpf-unexpected-control-unload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Unloaded` is fired when the control is removed from the WPF visual tree. As far as I've been able to read there is no "Unloading" event as there is, I think, in Windows Forms. But, "Unloaded" doesn't mean that the control is destroyed, just that it's removed from the visual tree.

Keep a reference to the control in a separate place in your code, along with a little bit of metadata about its parent control. You can probably collect that metadata by storing a reference to the `Parent` property in your `Initialized` event handler.

Then, when `Unloaded` is called, make your tests in the `Unloaded` event handler, and if your conditions are met, re-insert the control into the logical tree. The `ContentControl` class has an explicit `AddChild` protected method you could call.

There are probably some side effects to watch out for; According to the documentation, `Unloaded` is called when themes are changed at the OS level, when the WPF visual tree reconstitutes itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Unloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) event on System.Windows.Controls.Control, but I don't know an elegant way to stop unloading the control with it.

Comment: yea..i know about the unloaded event but depending on certain conditions I need to stop it from being unloaded...

Comment: Does it have to be a UserControl? Or could you use a modal dialog which doesn't close if certain conditions aren't met?

Answer (score -1):

```
private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (ConditionsMet) { e.Handled = true; }
}
```

If ConditionsMet the Unloaded event will be set to true henceforth keeping your control in the VisualTree - your control does not Unload

Comment: This does not work in my testing.  e.Handled = true; appears to be ignored.